# Using x-editable with reactjs, how to call editable function on items?

Tags: reactjs, x-editable

I am new to ReactJS, I am trying to create a Reactjs component that is a list of editable fields using x-editable.

According to x-editable documentation I need to call `.editable()` for each field, normally this is done accessing the element with jQuery.

How can I do it with React ? It has to be done when the component is mounted and I can't find a way to know when the component is rendered...

I would like to know the best way to achieve this ; I had a look at React `refs` but I am not sure it can help. So I ended up giving it a specific class, then using a selector
to call `editable()` on the fields, but it works only when the rendering has been done
and I don't find it very elegant.

**JS(X) code**:

```
var EditableField = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
         return <p>{this.props.name}: <a href="#" className="editable_field" name={this.prop.name} data-type="text" data-title="Edit value">{this.props.value}</a></p>
    }
});
```

**in script code**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
     $(".editable_field").editable();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do it in the `componentDidMount` function. This function is called when the component is mounted and the DOM is ready. Read more about the lifecycle here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Example (using refs instead of class selector):

```
var EditableField = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $(this.refs.editable.getDOMNode()).editable()
    },
    render: function() {
         return <p>{this.props.name}: <a href="#" ref="editable" name={this.prop.name} data-type="text" data-title="Edit value">{this.props.value}</a></p>
    }
});
```

Note that many "jquery plugins" will do heavy DOM manipulations and that does not always play well with React.

Comment: You said "Note that many "jquery plugins" will do heavy DOM manipulations and that does not always play well with React." 
So that means making use of X-Editable in React does not look to be fully compatible. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-x-editable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-x-editable)(react version of x-editable).Currently not all option supported.I will try to support most of options.